# mysql assign different partition for specific DB

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using mysql version 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu) with few DB & one of the DB is growing very rapidly and eating up disk space.

I have mounted secondary disk & would like this specific DB only to use this new added disk.

can someone please provide some suggestions how it can be done? can I move single DB to new disk or I have to move all DBs / mysql to new ? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:
[How can I move a MySQL database to another drive?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14320/how-can-i-move-a-mysql-database-to-another-drive)

> 1. Shutdown mysql.
> 2. Move all the files in your current data directory to
>      the new location (check out the location in step 3 - datadir
>      parameter).
> 3. Locate my.ini file (it is in the mysql installation
>      directory). Change datadir parameter value to point to the new
>      location.
> 4. Start mysql.

Comment: Won't this move all DBs?

Comment: I think u cant move only one DB. I have to move ALL db.

(i apologize for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't change your Database directory with one command.

You must move each of table to new Driver:

For do this (tested on MySQL 5.6):

1. Make sure innodb_file_per_table is ON
2. Run SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table and save all create command.
3. Run each create command and add _new to table name and DATA DIRECTORY = 'path' at the end of file too all of them for example:

   CREATE TABLE t1_new (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) DATA DIRECTORY = '/alternative/directory';
4. run Insert for all tables to move data to _new table example:

   INSERT INTO t1_new select * from t1
5. After move all tables to new table you can drop gracefully all old tables

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your valueable suggestions. I was not able to move single DB only. I found solutions to move all DB :( any how this is how I did.
still searching to move single DB solution,,,

this is how I managed to move mysql db to new drive.

-Stop mysql service **
-copy /var/lib/mysql folder to new drive using rsync to preserve permissions. **
-edit mysql inf file and point new folder for data dir  **
-add entry for new folder in apparmour start mysql ,

All done. documented [here](https://aacable.wordpress.com/2017/06/16/quick-notes-on-moving-mysql-databases-to-new-partition/).